# Comparing first and last row of groupby and creating new value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with multiple values and would like to groupby the 'email' column, retrieve the first row and last row, and compare to see if there is a change in the status of the category column. For example, if the category is from MGR to MGR, then there is no change. If the category changes from EMP to MGR, then it reflects a change in status.

```
date                 email               category
13-04-2018            johnson@abc.com     MGR
13-04-2018            linsay@abc.com      EMP
18-04-2018            kelphil@abc.com     EMP
20-04-2018            rsling@abc.com      MGR
11-01-2019            johnson@abc.com     MGR
15-10-2019            johnson@abc.com     MGR
16-11-2019            kelphil@abc.com     MGR
31-01-2020            sanson@abc.com      EMP
02-05-2020            rsling@abc.com      MGR
05-08-2020            rsling@abc.com      MGR
14-02-2021            sanson@abc.com      MGR
15-02-2021            linsay@abc.com      MGR
```

Would like to get the following results

```
date                 email               category    status
13-04-2018            johnson@abc.com     MGR        no change
15-10-2019            johnson@abc.com     MGR        no change
13-04-2018            linsay@abc.com      EMP        change
15-02-2021            linsay@abc.com      MGR        change
18-04-2018            kelphil@abc.com     EMP        change 
16-11-2019            kelphil@abc.com     MGR        change 
20-04-2018            rsling@abc.com      MGR        no change
05-08-2020            rsling@abc.com      MGR        no change
31-01-2020            sanson@abc.com      EMP        change 
14-02-2021            sanson@abc.com      MGR        change
```

I've tried the following code, but it seems to only retrieve the first and last rows based on the groupby. Is there some method to compare the values between the first and last row?

```
#get the first and last row of the groupby
df2 = df.groupby('email', as_index=False).nth([0,-1])
```

appreciate any form of help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it is effecient enough, but it works well.

```py
def check_status(group):
    selected = [False] * len(group)
    selected[0] = selected[-1] = True
    new_group = group[selected]
    new_group['status'] = 'change' if new_group.category.is_unique else 'no change'
    return new_group

print(df.groupby('email').apply(check_status).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Comment: this seems to work! Do you mind explaining what does
selected = [False] * len(group) do?

Comment: Well, it means that `selected` is a list where every element is `False` and its length equals to `len(group)`. I use it to select the first and the last ones in the group. I suppose there is some way in pandas that can do it more elegantly but I failed to find it. @wjie08

Answer (score 0):

try:

This will check whether groupby elements have the consecutive(same values or not) if there is any change it will set the flag.

```
fl = lambda s: s.iloc[[0,-1]]
res = df.groupby('email')['category'].apply(lambda x: (fl(x).shift(1).ne(fl(x)) & (fl(x).nunique()>1)))
res.index = res.index.droplevel()
df['status'] = res
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df['status'] = np.where(df.status,  'Change', 'No Change')
```

---

**df.sort_values(by='email'):**

|  | date | email | category | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 13-04-2018 | johnson@abc.com | MGR | No Change |
| 5 | 15-10-2019 | johnson@abc.com | MGR | No Change |
| 2 | 18-04-2018 | kelphil@abc.com | EMP | Change |
| 6 | 16-11-2019 | kelphil@abc.com | MGR | Change |
| 1 | 13-04-2018 | linsay@abc.com | EMP | Change |
| 11 | 15-02-2021 | linsay@abc.com | MGR | Change |
| 3 | 20-04-2018 | rsling@abc.com | MGR | No Change |
| 9 | 05-08-2020 | rsling@abc.com | MGR | No Change |
| 7 | 31-01-2020 | sanson@abc.com | EMP | Change |
| 10 | 14-02-2021 | sanson@abc.com | MGR | Change |

Comment: this works but is it possible to have the first row reflect the status that matches the last row? Meaning for kelphil@abc.com, we have status = 'changed' at index = 2.

Comment: @wjie08: I have updated my answer. Can you check it now?